# How to define backend batch dot method in keras tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I am loading two matrices (size: 10x32x32 each) from MATLAB. I want to train a model using keras tensorflow using custom loss function via Lambda layer. Both the matrices are fed as input to the model. But I am running into an error saying Model is not defined. I am unable to understand whether the error has occurred due to dimension mismatch of the matrices in the backend.batchdot method or whether the connections are not proper in the model especially when I am defining the Lambda layer for the loss function (rate in the code).

Please find the code implementation. I am quite new to this domain so needed some help.

```
"""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import numpy
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

# ------------------------------------------
#  Load and generate simulation data
# ------------------------------------------


W_shape=1024
M=4
N=4
Nt=2
sigma_2=pow(1.5,2);
##define to load data from MATLAB
#def mat_load(path):
print('loading data...')
# load the beamforming matrix
W = sio.loadmat( 'train_set/BF_matrix.mat')['W2']
hm = sio.loadmat('train_set/h_m.mat')['H2']
print('loading complete')

def Rate_func(temp):
    h, b, SNR_input = temp
    #b=tf.squeeze(b,axis=[0,1])
    hv = tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(
        tf.cast(h, tf.complex64), b)
    print('The shape of hv is: ', hv)
    print('The shape of h is: ', h.shape)
    #print('The shape of v is: ', v.shape)
    print('The shape of SNR_input is: ', SNR_input.shape)
    rate = tf.math.log(tf.cast(1 + SNR_input / Nt * tf.pow(tf.abs(hv), 2), tf.float32)) / tf.math.log(2.0)
    return -rate

# generate  SNRs associated with different samples
##CHECK THIS
SNR = np.power(10, np.random.randint(0, 20))
# use the estimated bf as the input of the BFNN
W_input = np.expand_dims(np.concatenate([np.real(W), np.imag(W)], 1), 1)
# -----------------------
#  Construct the BFNN Model
# -----------------------
# imperfect CSI is used to output the vrf
imperfect_BF = Input(name='imperfect_BF', shape=(W.shape[2:4]), dtype=tf.complex64)
perfect_CSI = Input(name='perfect_CSI', shape=(hm.shape[1:4]), dtype=tf.complex64)
# the SNR is also fed into the BFNN
SNR_input = Input(name='SNR_input', shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)

temp = BatchNormalization()(imperfect_BF)
#temp = BatchNormalization()(perfect_CSI)
temp = Flatten()(temp)
temp = BatchNormalization()(temp)
temp = Dense(256, activation='relu')(temp)
temp = BatchNormalization()(temp)
temp = Dense(128, activation='relu')(temp)

rate = Lambda(Rate_func, dtype=tf.float32, output_shape=(1,))([perfect_CSI, imperfect_BF, SNR_input])
model = Model(inputs=[imperfect_BF, perfect_CSI, SNR_input], outputs=rate)
# the y_pred is the actual rate, thus the loss is y_pred, without labels
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred)
model.summary()

# -----------------------
#  Train Your Model
# -----------------------
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=20, min_lr=0.00005)
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('./temp_trained.h5', monitor='val_loss',
                                        verbose=2, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only=True)
model.fit(x=[W_input, hm, SNR], y=W, batch_size=256,
          epochs=500, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[reduce_lr, checkpoint])


# # -----------------------
# #  Test Your Model
# # -----------------------
rate = []
# model.load_weights('./0db.h5')
for snr in range(-20, 25, 5):
    SNR = np.power(10, np.ones([W.shape[0], 1]) * snr / 10)
    y = model.evaluate(x=[W_input, hm, SNR], y=W, batch_size=10)
    print(snr, y)
    rate.append(-y)
print(rate)
```

The error is:

```
 File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\sukanyad\documents\project\codes\otfs codes\otfs codes\bf_dnn_myversion02.py:96
    model = Model(inputs=[imperfect_BF, perfect_CSI, SNR_input], outputs=rate)

NameError: name 'Model' is not defined
```